# Background image disappears above 1024px

Tags: css, media-queries, background-image

Please can someone help me. I have created a website which uses background images. It was working fine a few hours ago but not there seems to be a problem with the way they resize.

If you go here http://culturesmartbooks.co.uk/regions/asia.php it is working fine.

However, on the page http://culturesmartbooks.co.uk/regions/australasia.php, when browser is above 1024px the background image disappears.

Here is the HTML for the Asia page:

```
<div class="asiaHero">
<div class="caption">
    <h1>Asia</h1>
    <img src="../images/logoBlue.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .asiaHero {
      background-image: url("../images/asiaHero.jpg");
      height: 1000px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .asiaHero .caption {  
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;
    }

      .asiaHero .caption img {
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
    }

    /* sm */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .asiaHero .caption img {
            width: 300px;
        }
    }
    /* md */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .asiaHero .caption img {
            width: 400px;
        }
    }
    /* lg */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .asiaHero .caption img {
            width: 500px;
        }
    }

     @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .asiaHero {
      background-attachment: scroll;
      max-height: 650px;
      background-position: top;
    }
    .asiaHero .caption {  
      top: 50%;
  }
```

Australasia:

```
<div class="australasiaHero">
<div class="caption">
    <h1>Australasia</h1>
    <img src="../images/logoBlue.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .australasiaHero {
      background-image: url("../images/australasiaHero.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .australasiaHero .caption {  
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;
    }

      .australasiaHero .caption img {
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
    }

    /* sm */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .australasiaHero .caption img {
            width: 300px;
        }
    }
    /* md */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .australasiaHero .caption img {
            width: 400px;
        }
    }
    /* lg */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .australasiaHero .caption img {
            width: 500px;
        }
    }

     @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .australasiaHero {
      background-attachment: scroll;
      max-height: 650px;
      background-position: top;
    }
    .australasiaHero .caption {  
      top: 50%;
  }
```

I cannot see why Asia would display and Australasia would not. Please can someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why did you write the css inside media? http://prntscr.com/f1ugsz

remove media and write the styles as default and it will work fine.